# Assign Date to PivotTable in Excel

Tags: excel

So,

I cannot find a solution.
I have a very large file with timesteps from 1950 to 1970, daily.
I want to plot the date on the x axis with its values on the y axis.
So I marked my values with the dates, clicked on "Insert" and then "PivotChart" and everything looks fine.
I want to define the timesteps shown on the x-Axis (Just every second year i.e.) but it seems that the PivotChart does not recognize that my x-Axis values are dates.

Any Ideas how I can change that?!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possibly one, or more, of what looks like a date in your source data is really a string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Well how would I change that?
`=DATEVALUE()` does not help (I tried that on my Date column already). It returnes `#VALUE!`

Comment: First check all the entries in your source data with `=ISTEXT(cell_ref)` to see if any are text.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld no there arent. All `false`

Comment: Then that is not the problem.  Can you post a copy of your data on a public site, and post a link here (remove any sensitive information) and I will take a look at it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld 
When I right click on the x-Axix, Format Axis I can choose the Interval Unit which Excel wants in numbers... I can chose "Axis Type" as well and chosed "Date Axis" bust that did not do the trick neither...

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry. Thats all senstive...

Comment: Why not use a Line chart?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a Pivot Chart according to the [Display dates on a category axis](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Display-dates-on-a-category-axis-d5a8146b-d457-43d1-8602-c1d23c96d650#bm1) article at support.office.com.

I suppose you'll need to use a Line chart if you want to display by every two years.

You can also group the data in the Pivot Table, which will cause a corresponding change in the Pivot Chart.  In Excel 2007, that was limited to every year -- without an option for multiple years (as there is for days).  But perhaps that has changed in later versions?